# How to determine if this sequence converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to determine if this sequence converges or diverges?
 if it converge can someone show me, but if it diverges how can we know all the sub-limit of it?

$$a_{n\:=\:}\sqrt[n]{\left(2^{\left(n\left(-1\right)^n\right)}\:+3^{\left(n\left(-1\right)^n\right)}\:\right)^{\:}}$$

Comment: Consider the subsequences with odd resp. even indices.

Comment: @DanielFischer tnx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=2k$, 
$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[2k]{2^{2k\left(-1\right)^{2k}}+3^{2k\left(-1\right)^{2k}}}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[2k]{2^{2k}+3^{2k}}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left(4^{k}+9^{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{2k}}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}e^{\ln\left(4^{k}+9^{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{2k}}}= e^{ \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(4^{k}+9^{k}\right)}{2k}} $$
$$= e^{\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dk}\left[\ln\left(4^{k}+9^{k}\right)\right]}{2\frac{d}{dk}[k]}} = e^{\frac12\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{4^{k}\ln(4)+9^{k}\ln(9)}{4^{k}+9^{k}}} $$
$$ =e^{\frac12\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{\frac{4^{k}\ln(4)}{9^k}+\ln(9)}{\frac{4^{k}}{9^k}+1}} =e^{\frac12 \ln(9)} $$
$$ =e^{\ln(3)}=3 $$
Therefore when $n$ is even, the sequence converges to $3$. Now just do the same for $n=2k+1$.